# Look up multiple e-mail addresses by deserializing JSON with regex

Tags: arrays, regex, json

We are working on an application that retrieves data from an external source. By processing the data the JSON must be manipulated before deserializing . So far so good.

A problem occurs when a JSON element contains multiple values. For example:

> "CcRecipients":[{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"foo@example.com","Name":"FirstName
>   LastName"}},{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"bar@example.com","Name":"FirstName1
>   LastName1"}}],

What we are looking for is an regex that will retrieve all occurrences of

> {"EmailAddress":{"Address":"foo@example.com","Name":"FirstName LastName"}},

I've already created a regex for a single occurence:

```
(\[\{"\w+":\{"\w+":"\w+@\w+\d.\w+.\w{3}","\w{4}":"\w+\s+\w+"\}\},\])
```

Anyone an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What that `\d` there for? I wouldn't use regex for that, what language are you using?

Comment: There's no difference between a regex for _one_ occurence and _all_ occurences, is there? You just use the same regex multiple times or set the `g` modifier.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to manipulate the JSON before deserializing it to some data-structure your language supports. If nothing else you could deserialize, manipulate and then serialize again to send it to another process? Regexes aren't your best option to analyze JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

`\d` is not required. Also you need to escape `.`.

Can you try this:

```
input.match(/{"\w+":{"\w+":"\w+@\w+\.\w{3}","\w{4}":"\w+\s+\w+"}}/g);
```